# Perform some common stuff when commiting into database

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate as ORM tool, i want to perform some common stuff for all the entities that i flush into the database.

Currently , whenever i save object into database, i perforrm following steps :-

1. Open session
2. Begin a Transaction
3. Create Te Object
4. save the object using `session.save(object);`
5. commit the transaction if save is successfull. otherwise rollback transasction.
6. close the session.

Now, i want to perform some post-save and pre-flush checks, is there any way to do so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement 'preFlush' method of [Interceptor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/class-use/Interceptor.html). Check [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html) for hibernate interceptor.